# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS - can 't empty trash, rm'd from Terminal - Trash folder gone but Trashcan still full!

Tags: command-line, nautilus, delete, trash

First time using a Linux dual boot Windows computer. I can't empty my trash (very full with VERY big files - I work in a bio lab). When I try to do it through the GUI it says "Preparing" and then just remains stuck on this forever (I have left it overnight and no difference)

I have tried to do it through the Terminal using the following command:

```
sudo  rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash
```

Now the Trash folder is completely gone from the file system but my trashcan is still full!

After doing this rm if I try to find the Trash directory in terminal using "find" it is completely missing. It is no longer in the ~/.local/share even though it was there before.

This would all be fine but my Trashcan is still full. Any suggestions?

Here are specs: 
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Intel® Core™ i7-3820 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8

Graphics - ATI R520

GNOME - 3.28.2

64-bit OS

Comment: Try recreating the trash folder `mkdir ~/.local/share/Trash`.

Comment: The trash also lists the trashed files of other mounted disks: try deleting `<mountpoint>/.Trash-$UID/files/*`.

Answer (score 3):

I use `$ trash-empty` from the " trash-cli " package (`$ sudo apt install trash-cli`).

This link provides three more ways to empty trash in Ubuntu: https://vitux.com/four-ways-to-empty-the-trash-recycle-bin-in-ubuntu/ .
Sorry, for your deleted Trashcan I do not know of a solution to propose :( .